# How do I prevent a redirect from happening while developing a web app in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I did not write the code for the app, and I need to refactor it. When I launch one of the pages, there is some error in the app and the app redirects, but I don't have time to see what happened in Chrome Dev Tools.

How can I prevent any redirect from happening?

Comment: You could add a debugger in code where the error is caused, so that the execution pauses before redirection.

Comment: at least, you can set several `console.log` to print to chrome console and figure out what is going on

Comment: You can set both the Console and Network tabs to "preserve log" so that even if a new request occurs you can see the logs which were made in the previous page.

Comment: @MarkC. I think it means that the page redirection happens so fast that there's physically no time to look at the console entries before the redirect occurs (and thus the console entries are cleared out). That can potentially be remedied by either or both of the ideas from abd995's and my comments.

Comment: @ADyson true, the question is too ambiguous without enough level of detail to know what debugging steps have been taken. Regardless I think you're probably right and I took it as a literal time limitation and not the speed of the redirect. Thank you

Comment: @MarkC. I see an error in Chrome Dev Tools for a split second and then the redirect happens. I believe the redirect happens because some error happened. Stopping the redirect will let me see what that error was.

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres from the description it sounds like adding console entries isn't the issue, it's having the time to read them before they are cleared out (due to the redirect clearing the console)

Comment: @evianpring look at mine and abd995's comments to see ways you can overcome this issue.

Comment: @ADyson sorry, I wasn't clear enough. In developer console settings you can enable persistent logs that doesn't get removed by the redirect